# All values are sometimes 0 when submitting form data in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, forms, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting numbers form 12 input fields and when I submit the form, sometimes all the values would be 0. This happens only like 1/10 times when submitting, other times, it works just fine. Is there something wrong? Maybe the submit function runs before the form data is collected? There is no place for mistake in my application. Please help.

Below is my code:

ts file:

```
async onSubmit() {
  this.getData();
  this.aioServ.submitForm(this.data)
}

getData() {

  this.data = {
    month: (document.getElementById("month") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    year: (document.getElementById("year") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a1: +(document.getElementById("a1") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b1: +(document.getElementById("b1") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a2: +(document.getElementById("a2") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b2: +(document.getElementById("b2") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a3: +(document.getElementById("a3") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b3: Math.trunc(+((3 / 100) * this.sc[0]?.population)),
    a4: +(document.getElementById("a4") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a5: +(document.getElementById("a5") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b5: +this.sc[0]?.thirtyPlus,
    a6: +(document.getElementById("a6") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b6: +this.sc[0]?.thirtyPlus,
    a7: +(document.getElementById("a7") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b7: +this.sc[0]?.thirtyPlus,
    a8: +(document.getElementById("a8") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a9: +(document.getElementById("a9") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a10: +(document.getElementById("a10") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b10: +(document.getElementById("b10") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a11: +(document.getElementById("a11") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b11: +(document.getElementById("b11") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    a12: +(document.getElementById("a12") as HTMLInputElement).value,
    b12: +(document.getElementById("b12") as HTMLInputElement).value,
  };
  console.log("Get Data: ", this.data);
```

}

aioService file.ts:

```
 submitForm(data) {
        this.afs.firestore.collection('reports').doc(`${calculation.documentName}`).get().then(async     
    docSnapshot => {
      if(docSnapshot.exists) {
        const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: 'Error',
          message: 'Report already submitted for the selected month!',
          buttons: ['Dismiss']
        });
        await alert.present();
      }
      else {
        this.reportsCollection.doc(`${calculation.documentName}`).set(calculation);
      }
    })
  }
```

I have not tried other methods because I don't currently know any other solutions that I can try.

Comment: It seems like you have an Angular application, why don't you use [Angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) to collect the data from the input fields?

Comment: Do you mean Reactive forms?

Comment: In your use case, [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) seem to be the right choice. Definitely much better than using `document.getElementById('').value`. It is likely that with Reactive Forms you will not have such issues.

Comment: Thank you, will try with reactive forms and I will let you know